# When is it time to replace a hard drive? - badblocks - 167/0/0 errors -

Tags: hard-drive

**When is it time to replace a hard drive?** This is what i am getting on my machine. `Pass completed, 167 bad blocks found. (167/0/0 errors)`

It's a 500GB hard drive (not solid state). I did have windows7 on the machine but it was very slow and I just put ubuntu16 on it and did this check on the hard drive knowing that it was not right. (I did a chkdisk on windows before) So I was planning on changing the HD anyhow(when i get the time), although ubuntu seems alot better/quicker than W7 at this stage, although it is a fresh install the first thing I have done is the `badblocks check`.

Also following my badblocks output below I was hoping to paste the content in to a file. But I could not I kept getting `read only file system`. I have looked up this and hoping it is okay when I turn it on again. But it could be the actual harddrive is so bad that it goes into this state. But it is obviously good enough to do a freshinstall of ubuntu. **Could you comment on this also in relation to my main question?**

This is the output of my badblocks run

```
$ sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sda
[sudo] password for abc: 
Checking blocks 0 to 488386583
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test):   0.00% done, 0:00 elapsed. (0/0/0 err473988688one, 2:12:03 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)
473988689one, 2:12:06 elapsed. (1/0/0 errors)
473988690one, 2:12:09 elapsed. (2/0/0 errors)
473988691one, 2:12:11 elapsed. (3/0/0 errors)
478261892one, 2:14:00 elapsed. (4/0/0 errors)
478261893one, 2:14:03 elapsed. (5/0/0 errors)
478261894one, 2:14:06 elapsed. (6/0/0 errors)
478261895one, 2:14:09 elapsed. (7/0/0 errors)
478262348one, 2:14:14 elapsed. (8/0/0 errors)
478262349one, 2:14:17 elapsed. (9/0/0 errors)
478262350one, 2:14:19 elapsed. (10/0/0 errors)
478262351one, 2:14:22 elapsed. (11/0/0 errors)
478262352one, 2:14:25 elapsed. (12/0/0 errors)
478262353one, 2:14:27 elapsed. (13/0/0 errors)
478262354one, 2:14:30 elapsed. (14/0/0 errors)
478262355one, 2:14:33 elapsed. (15/0/0 errors)
478263336one, 2:14:41 elapsed. (16/0/0 errors)
478263337one, 2:14:44 elapsed. (17/0/0 errors)
478263338one, 2:14:46 elapsed. (18/0/0 errors)
478263339one, 2:14:49 elapsed. (19/0/0 errors)
478263796one, 2:14:54 elapsed. (20/0/0 errors)
478263797one, 2:14:56 elapsed. (21/0/0 errors)
478263798one, 2:14:58 elapsed. (22/0/0 errors)
478263799one, 2:15:00 elapsed. (23/0/0 errors)
478263800one, 2:15:03 elapsed. (24/0/0 errors)
478263801one, 2:15:06 elapsed. (25/0/0 errors)
478263802one, 2:15:08 elapsed. (26/0/0 errors)
478263803one, 2:15:11 elapsed. (27/0/0 errors)
478264260one, 2:15:16 elapsed. (28/0/0 errors)
478264261one, 2:15:19 elapsed. (29/0/0 errors)
478264262one, 2:15:21 elapsed. (30/0/0 errors)
478264263one, 2:15:24 elapsed. (31/0/0 errors)
478264720one, 2:15:29 elapsed. (32/0/0 errors)
478264721one, 2:15:32 elapsed. (33/0/0 errors)
478264722one, 2:15:34 elapsed. (34/0/0 errors)
478264723one, 2:15:37 elapsed. (35/0/0 errors)
478265180one, 2:15:41 elapsed. (36/0/0 errors)
478265181one, 2:15:44 elapsed. (37/0/0 errors)
478265182one, 2:15:46 elapsed. (38/0/0 errors)
478265183one, 2:15:48 elapsed. (39/0/0 errors)
478265640one, 2:15:54 elapsed. (40/0/0 errors)
478265641one, 2:15:56 elapsed. (41/0/0 errors)
478265642one, 2:15:59 elapsed. (42/0/0 errors)
478265643one, 2:16:02 elapsed. (43/0/0 errors)
478266104one, 2:16:07 elapsed. (44/0/0 errors)
478266105one, 2:16:09 elapsed. (45/0/0 errors)
478266106one, 2:16:12 elapsed. (46/0/0 errors)
478266107one, 2:16:15 elapsed. (47/0/0 errors)
478273480one, 2:16:21 elapsed. (48/0/0 errors)
478293736one, 2:16:29 elapsed. (49/0/0 errors)
478293737one, 2:16:31 elapsed. (50/0/0 errors)
478293738one, 2:16:34 elapsed. (51/0/0 errors)
478293739one, 2:16:37 elapsed. (52/0/0 errors)
478294196one, 2:16:43 elapsed. (53/0/0 errors)
478294197one, 2:16:46 elapsed. (54/0/0 errors)
478294198one, 2:16:49 elapsed. (55/0/0 errors)
478294199one, 2:16:52 elapsed. (56/0/0 errors)
478294656one, 2:16:57 elapsed. (57/0/0 errors)
478294657one, 2:17:00 elapsed. (58/0/0 errors)
478294658one, 2:17:02 elapsed. (59/0/0 errors)
478294659one, 2:17:05 elapsed. (60/0/0 errors)
478295120one, 2:17:11 elapsed. (61/0/0 errors)
478295121one, 2:17:14 elapsed. (62/0/0 errors)
478295122one, 2:17:16 elapsed. (63/0/0 errors)
478295123one, 2:17:19 elapsed. (64/0/0 errors)
478297948one, 2:17:25 elapsed. (65/0/0 errors)
478297949one, 2:17:28 elapsed. (66/0/0 errors)
478297950one, 2:17:30 elapsed. (67/0/0 errors)
478297951one, 2:17:33 elapsed. (68/0/0 errors)
478298408one, 2:17:38 elapsed. (69/0/0 errors)
478298409one, 2:17:40 elapsed. (70/0/0 errors)
478298410one, 2:17:43 elapsed. (71/0/0 errors)
478298411one, 2:17:45 elapsed. (72/0/0 errors)
478298868one, 2:17:50 elapsed. (73/0/0 errors)
478298869one, 2:17:52 elapsed. (74/0/0 errors)
478298870one, 2:17:54 elapsed. (75/0/0 errors)
478298871one, 2:17:56 elapsed. (76/0/0 errors)
478299328one, 2:18:02 elapsed. (77/0/0 errors)
478299329one, 2:18:04 elapsed. (78/0/0 errors)
478299330one, 2:18:07 elapsed. (79/0/0 errors)
478299331one, 2:18:10 elapsed. (80/0/0 errors)
478299792one, 2:18:14 elapsed. (81/0/0 errors)
478299793one, 2:18:16 elapsed. (82/0/0 errors)
478299794one, 2:18:18 elapsed. (83/0/0 errors)
478299795one, 2:18:21 elapsed. (84/0/0 errors)
478300780one, 2:18:26 elapsed. (85/0/0 errors)
478300781one, 2:18:28 elapsed. (86/0/0 errors)
478300782one, 2:18:31 elapsed. (87/0/0 errors)
478300783one, 2:18:34 elapsed. (88/0/0 errors)
480276628one, 2:19:26 elapsed. (89/0/0 errors)
480276629one, 2:19:29 elapsed. (90/0/0 errors)
480276630one, 2:19:32 elapsed. (91/0/0 errors)
480276631one, 2:19:34 elapsed. (92/0/0 errors)
486866560one, 2:22:46 elapsed. (93/0/0 errors)
486866561one, 2:22:49 elapsed. (94/0/0 errors)
486866562one, 2:22:52 elapsed. (95/0/0 errors)
486866563one, 2:22:54 elapsed. (96/0/0 errors)
486866584one, 2:22:59 elapsed. (97/0/0 errors)
486866585one, 2:23:03 elapsed. (98/0/0 errors)
486866586one, 2:23:06 elapsed. (99/0/0 errors)
486866587one, 2:23:09 elapsed. (100/0/0 errors)
486879824one, 2:23:15 elapsed. (101/0/0 errors)
486879825one, 2:23:18 elapsed. (102/0/0 errors)
486879826one, 2:23:21 elapsed. (103/0/0 errors)
486879827one, 2:23:25 elapsed. (104/0/0 errors)
486889488one, 2:23:32 elapsed. (105/0/0 errors)
486889489one, 2:23:35 elapsed. (106/0/0 errors)
486889490one, 2:23:38 elapsed. (107/0/0 errors)
486889491one, 2:23:42 elapsed. (108/0/0 errors)
486889552one, 2:23:53 elapsed. (109/0/0 errors)
486889553one, 2:23:57 elapsed. (110/0/0 errors)
486889554one, 2:24:02 elapsed. (111/0/0 errors)
486889555one, 2:24:05 elapsed. (112/0/0 errors)
486896552one, 2:24:13 elapsed. (113/0/0 errors)
486896553one, 2:24:17 elapsed. (114/0/0 errors)
486896554one, 2:24:19 elapsed. (115/0/0 errors)
486896555one, 2:24:22 elapsed. (116/0/0 errors)
486897408one, 2:24:30 elapsed. (117/0/0 errors)
486897409one, 2:24:34 elapsed. (118/0/0 errors)
486897410one, 2:24:37 elapsed. (119/0/0 errors)
486897424one, 2:24:45 elapsed. (120/0/0 errors)
486897428one, 2:24:50 elapsed. (121/0/0 errors)
486897429one, 2:24:53 elapsed. (122/0/0 errors)
486897430one, 2:24:56 elapsed. (123/0/0 errors)
486897431one, 2:25:00 elapsed. (124/0/0 errors)
486897440one, 2:25:05 elapsed. (125/0/0 errors)
486897441one, 2:25:07 elapsed. (126/0/0 errors)
486897444one, 2:25:12 elapsed. (127/0/0 errors)
486897464one, 2:25:26 elapsed. (128/0/0 errors)
486897465one, 2:25:29 elapsed. (129/0/0 errors)
486897466one, 2:25:35 elapsed. (130/0/0 errors)
486897467one, 2:25:38 elapsed. (131/0/0 errors)
486897484one, 2:25:55 elapsed. (132/0/0 errors)
486897485one, 2:25:58 elapsed. (133/0/0 errors)
486897486one, 2:26:01 elapsed. (134/0/0 errors)
486897487one, 2:26:06 elapsed. (135/0/0 errors)
486897900one, 2:26:38 elapsed. (136/0/0 errors)
486897901one, 2:26:42 elapsed. (137/0/0 errors)
486897902one, 2:26:48 elapsed. (138/0/0 errors)
486897903one, 2:26:51 elapsed. (139/0/0 errors)
486898772one, 2:27:22 elapsed. (140/0/0 errors)
486898773one, 2:27:25 elapsed. (141/0/0 errors)
486898774one, 2:27:28 elapsed. (142/0/0 errors)
486898775one, 2:27:31 elapsed. (143/0/0 errors)
486898776one, 2:27:36 elapsed. (144/0/0 errors)
486898777one, 2:27:40 elapsed. (145/0/0 errors)
486898778one, 2:27:45 elapsed. (146/0/0 errors)
486898779one, 2:27:50 elapsed. (147/0/0 errors)
486900952one, 2:27:59 elapsed. (148/0/0 errors)
486900953one, 2:28:02 elapsed. (149/0/0 errors)
486900954one, 2:28:04 elapsed. (150/0/0 errors)
486900964one, 2:28:10 elapsed. (151/0/0 errors)
486900965one, 2:28:12 elapsed. (152/0/0 errors)
486900966one, 2:28:15 elapsed. (153/0/0 errors)
486900967one, 2:28:18 elapsed. (154/0/0 errors)
486900968one, 2:28:21 elapsed. (155/0/0 errors)
486900969one, 2:28:24 elapsed. (156/0/0 errors)
486900970one, 2:28:27 elapsed. (157/0/0 errors)
486900971one, 2:28:30 elapsed. (158/0/0 errors)
486901008one, 2:28:47 elapsed. (159/0/0 errors)
486901009one, 2:28:52 elapsed. (160/0/0 errors)
486901010one, 2:28:57 elapsed. (161/0/0 errors)
486901011one, 2:29:00 elapsed. (162/0/0 errors)
486901384one, 2:29:12 elapsed. (163/0/0 errors)
486901385one, 2:29:15 elapsed. (164/0/0 errors)
486901386one, 2:29:17 elapsed. (165/0/0 errors)
486901387one, 2:29:20 elapsed. (166/0/0 errors)
done                                                 
Pass completed, 167 bad blocks found. (167/0/0 errors)
```

Answer (score 1):

With 167 bad blocks I would say goodbye to that disk :( But first I would run some smartmontools tests on it as well.

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools
```

Comment: tks, what would that hope to achieve. I surmise that it would have very small chance of fixing it? Or would I get a better understanding of the issue?

Comment: I bet there is no chance of fixing this. Since many years the "modern" hard disks already have a way of "fixing" bad blocks themselves. The moment that bad block really appear to you would mean that the disk already has failed to deal with them. I would run a smartctl test just to double check.